# Update query with a dynamic expression in Drupal 7?

Tags: database

```
db_update('warrior_members')
          ->fields(array('points' => 'points' +1))//This is not working
          ->condition('uid', $liv_user)
          ->execute();
```

### How to increase the cell at 1?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use an expression: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/function/UpdateQuery%3A%3Aexpression/7

Example:

```
db_update('warrior_members')
  ->expression('points', 'points + 1')
  ->condition('uid', $liv_user)
  ->execute();
```

Or to make the 1 dynamic:

```
db_update('warrior_members')
  ->expression('points', 'points + :amount', array(':amount' => 1))
  ->condition('uid', $liv_user)
  ->execute();
```