# db_update add value to field

Tags: database

I want use `db_update` to update a field,instead of update a field with new value (replace) , I want add a value to last value, 
I know I can do it with mysql command

```
UPDATE `databasename`.`tablename` SET fieldB = fieldB + 1 WHERE fieldA='2';
```

but I use below code, It is not add to credit field, only replace it with $credit value, 
anybody know where is my problem and how can I achieve this job?

```
$cr_update_no = db_update('rah_cc_credit') // Table name no longer needs {}
                ->fields(array('uid' => $user->uid,'update_date'=>REQUEST_TIME,'last_code'=>$code ,'credit' => 'credit'+ $credit))
                ->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=')
                ->execute();
```

Comment: @Jimajamma no , It +1 to pervious value, how can I add $credit to it??  'credit+ $credit' will not work

Comment: you can put anything in there instead of 1, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/update-query-with-a-dynamic-expression-in-drupal-7, I only linked the first q&a in because your static query used 1.

Comment: @Jimajamma you say my answer is  ` db_update('rah_cc_credit') // Table name no longer needs {}
                ->fields(array('uid' => $user->uid,'update_date'=>REQUEST_TIME,'last_code'=>$code )
    ->expression('credit', 'credit + :amount', array(':amount' => $credit))
                ->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=')
                ->execute();` ?

Comment: that's what the various docs say should do it, yes; I haven't a testbed to debug it exactly here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is way I used to update,
for this job drupal has syntax, according to  [Update query with a dynamic expression in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/update-query-with-a-dynamic-expression-in-drupal-7)
I found my solution

```
$cr_update_no= db_update('rah_cc_credit') // Table name no longer needs {}
                ->fields(array('uid' => $user->uid,'update_date'=>REQUEST_TIME,'last_code'=>$code ))
                ->expression('credit', 'credit + :amount', array(':amount' => $credit))
                ->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=')
                ->execute();
```

I submit this answer maybe helpful for another in future.